# pexpect won't work for SCP

Tags: python, linux, expect, scp, pexpect

I have this code in Python written:

```
child = pexpect.spawn("scp -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no id_rsa.pub servername:~/.")
i = child.expect([pexpect.EOF, "", "Password: "])
    if i == 0:
        pass
    else:
        child.sendline(password)
        child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
```

Some of my servers have the public key added into the authorized list so it does not prompt for a password (which is why i have the EOF section). The second part is where I have servers that still require a password and need to get the public key added into the authorized_keys list.

I have Linux and Solaris boxes and what I don't understand is that in the Solaris boxes the scp command just hangs and eventually times out. I can't for the life of me figure out why the "Password: " is not working on the Solaris boxes. When I ran the command manually I get the same output as the Linux servers, but in Linux the above code works.

Does anyone have any idea why I can't seem to expect the scp command on my solaris boxes?

I've tried "Password:", "Password", "password", "password: ", ":" - but none of it works; here are the last few outputs when I run the scp command manually:

```
Solaris Release 10u9  --> Use only documents referencing 10u9


<LDAP>

Password:
```

Comment: 'Controlling SSH on Solaris' in http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/doc/ suggests that this is a possible problem with pexpect on Solaris, and your only option might be public key auth.  For what it's worth, I believe I got pexpect SSH login working on Solaris with some fiddling, albeit many years ago and in code I don't have access to any more.

Comment: Why do you have an empty string `""` as one of the matching options? I think that will either match everything, in which case it might well be causing a problem, or nothing, in which case you can take it out.